# Use browser to send modbus command

Tags: c#, http, tcp, modbus

I've got some piece of hardware that uses ModbusRTU. Using a TCP/IP Gateway for ModbusRTU I can now control the hardware using my C# application over TCP/IP. This works.

Now I would like to control it with my android phone. 
Yes, I could make an Android app, what should be no problem for me, but I want to make it more special for myself to fix it with the web browser. That way I'm even more flexible since other OS's should be no problem too.

I'm interested where I should start looking if I want to control the hardware by using the web browser. What programming language, what are the server requirements. 
Please mind that I've have very little experience with web browser programming but I'm eager to learn it. Did just some very simple things with PHP / Ajax.

Fyi, the ModbusTCP packeds are really simple, I only control some lights on/off/dimming at my home and to enable some equipment.

Comment: This is too broad to answer on SO, but I would start by writing an ASP.Net app to open a TCP connection and fire off a command (like your're already doing) on a post from the browser (could be a simple button click).

Comment: With @JonB. Please note that the website you're talking about is supposed to be merely a graphical shell, you should extract the logic into some kind of module. This module does the TCP talking to the device. You can wrap this module in a WCF service to execute its methods, and you can call those WCF actions from your website's code.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently playing with the Marmalade Quick beta which can open a TCP port in Lua. This is a simple high level language, with a build system for Android.

http://quick-docs.madewithmarmalade.com/

Which Modbus lighting controller are you using?

Comment: I'm having problems with CRC for Modbus in C#, be interested to see your implementation.